# Does OpenGL ES 2.0 require a shader for any vertex rendering?

Tags: android, opengl-es

GL10 class has `glVertexPointer` method.
GLES20 does not have this method, but has `glVertexAttribPointer`.

Does this mean that OpenGL ES 2.0 requires a having shader for rendering vertices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to create a vertex shader to handle the transformations, and a fragment shader that assigns the final color to a fragment (using texture sampling for example). The whole fixed-function pipeline has been removed in OpenGL-ES 2.0.