# OpenGL 4: Draw with glVertexAttrib

Tags: c++, opengl

Is it possible to draw in OpenGL 4+ just using **glVertexAttrib3f** calls? The following works in legacy OpenGL mode but when I switch to OpenGL 4 nothing gets rendered.

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
glVertexAttrib3f(1,  0, 0, -1);
glVertexAttrib3f(0, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5 );
glVertexAttrib3f(0, -0.5,  0.5, -0.5 );
glVertexAttrib3f(0,  0.5,  0.5, -0.5 );

glVertexAttrib3f(1,  0, 0, 1);
glVertexAttrib3f(0,  0.5, -0.5, 0.5 );
glVertexAttrib3f(0,  0.5,  0.5, 0.5 );
glVertexAttrib3f(0, -0.5,  0.5, 0.5 );
....
glEnd();
```

I suppose I should get rid of those glBegin() glEnd() functions and maybe call glDrawArrays() but haven't got it to work.

Comment: `glBegin` and `glEnd` do not exist in OpenGL 4.

Comment: I believe this should still work in the compatibility profile. Obviously not with a core profile context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glBegin/glEnd are deprecated legacy functionality and they are not the part of the OpenGL core profiles since version 3.1. In short they shouldn't be used anymore. If you want to use them in spite of that, you can, but in that case you must use the [compatibility profile](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_And_Compatibility_in_Contexts) in your OpenGL context, otherwise they are unsupported.

If you use [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org) for context and window creation, you can set the compatibility profile at the [context creation](https://open.gl/context#GLFW) with the following hint:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE);
```

I would strongly recommend the following tutorial sites

- http://open.gl
- http://www.opengl-tutorial.org

to learn about modern OpenGL functionality and usage.

Comment: You are right, but glBegin/glEnd are deprecated. After immediate mode rendering (glBegin/glEnd) gone deprecated, glVertexAttrib* functions only served the "default vertex constant" functionality I explained in my deleted answer.

Answer (score 0):

In OpenGL 3.3 and greater (maybe even just 3.0 and greater?) you cannot draw anything without specifying a shader program explicitly.

Also, in OpenGL ES 2.0 you need this.

[OpenGL: What's the deal with deprecation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218449/opengl-whats-the-deal-with-deprecation)

[Does OpenGL ES 2.0 require a shader for any vertex rendering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590335/does-opengl-es-2-0-require-a-shader-for-any-vertex-rendering)

Comment: Actually I am using shaders, the above works fine using shaders in pre OpenGL 4 and from what I saw glVertexAttrib3f is not deprecated.

Comment: Yeah `vertexAttrib3f` is not deprecated but I wasn't sure what you meant when you said "only ... calls" in side of `glBegin ... glEnd`